# .htaccess file not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I've literally being trying for a few days to get my .htaccess file to work

the .htaccess file is quiet simple, it contains the following

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 http://mydomain.com/search
```

However no matter what commands I paste into the the file I can not get anything to happen.

the file is under `/var/www/` on my Ubuntu server, and I have tried placing into in the root `/`, nothing works

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have either `AllowOverride All` or at the very least `AllowOverride FileInfo`. Htaccess files' contents are ignored if you don't have them.

Comment: This was a bit vague but after searching the web I realised that by default Ubuntu disables apache htacces, for anyone who may have this problem just follow this guide... line by line